# Detecting the dimension where a player is

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I want to check a player's current dimension using a scoreboard. For example, if a player is in the overworld, `scoreboard` would be set to 1. Nether would be 2. And the End would be 3.

I have tried `execute if entity @a in minecraft:the_nether` but that actually changes the coordinate's dimension.

Do you know any way to detect a player's current dimension?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's saved in NBT. Quote from the [Minecraft wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Player.dat_format#NBT_structure) ([archive](https://minecraft.wiki/w/index.php?title=Player.dat_format&oldid=1556683#NBT_structure)):

> **Dimension**: The dimension the player is in. -1 is the Nether, 0 is the Overworld, 1 is the End.

---

Alternatively, you could still use `/execute in`, but also check for a radius of 0 or more (which sounds useless, but can be used as a dimension check):

```
/execute in the_nether if entity @a[distance=0..] run …
```

This executes if there is a player in the Nether.

---

There is also an advancement trigger called "[`changed_dimension`](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Advancements/JSON_format#minecraft:changed_dimension)" ([archive](https://minecraft.wiki/w/index.php?title=Advancements/JSON_format&oldid=1548230#minecraft:changed_dimension)) that can be used to detect a change to a specified dimension and trigger something at that moment. Alternatively you could use the `dimension` field in the [`location` trigger](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Advancements/JSON_format#minecraft:location) ([archive](https://minecraft.wiki/w/index.php?title=Advancements/JSON_format&oldid=1548230#minecraft:location)).

Answer (score 1):

```
execute store result score @s dimension run data get entity @s Dimension
```

This will set the scoreboard value based on the length of the entity's dimension string.

20 - "minecraft:the_nether",
19 - "minecraft:overworld",
17 - "minecraft:the_end"

You can either have your functions handling dimensions instead with these numbers, or you can convert them.