# How do i detect when a player is in the nether or any other dimension to run a command?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Im new in making datapacks but, All im trying to do is make it detect when im in the minecraft:nether_1. So if im in the nether it will run the command "execute as @a at @s in minecraft:nether_2 run tp @s ~ ~ ~"

Comment: I still have no idea what you mean with "`nether_2`". This does not exist in Minecraft Vanilla.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detecting the dimension where a player is](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/359841/detecting-the-dimension-where-a-player-is)

Comment: @pppery Oh wow, I actually answered both almost identically without noticing. Good find!

Answer (score 1):

There is an advancement condition called `location` that can check for dimension.

In commands you can read out the "`Dimension`" field in NBT:

```
/say @a[nbt={Dimension:-1}]
```

This tells you all players in the Nether. `0` is Overworld, `1` is End.

It might give you slightly better performance to use this workaround:

```
/execute in the_nether run say @a[distance=0..]
```

With that, the game doesn't need to read any NBT and can use its already existing lists of players per dimension.